# Button in header when implementing StickyGridHeaders Android

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am trying to use [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) in my Android app and it is working great except when I try to add a clicklistener to a clickable ImageView in the headerview.  In `getHeaderView()` in my `BaseAdapter` I am trying to do the following:

**getHeaderView**

```
@Override
public View getHeaderView(final int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item,viewGroup, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView date =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    ImageView settings = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.folder_settings);

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "The Click Worked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    GalleryItem galleryItem = galleryItems.get(pos);

    icon.setImageResource(setIcon(galleryItem.getMode()));
    title.setText(galleryItem.getTitle());
    Date da = galleryItem.record.getDate("FILE_DATE");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL-dd-yyyy");
    String mDate = dateFormat.format(da);
    date.setText(mDate);

    return view;
}
```

**gallery_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@color/lightgraymain"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery_mode_tag" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="521 North 7th Street, Lincoln, NE"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="August-25-2014"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@color/gray" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/folder_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery_options"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot get the toast to appear. I have tried implementing `onHeaderClick()` in the adapter as well to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
-Zach

Comment: anybody? I would really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after hours and hours of mind numbing searching for this answer, I finally figured it out. I was looking through the example [here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) and noticed that in the header layout, they didn't specify the layout as

```
//remove the following from your header layout
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I **removed** these properties from my header view completely and viola! it works. I feel pretty dumb after that, but hope it helps someone else.

**UPDATE**

Here is a little more detail in how I have implemented it.

**Fragment Class**

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements      
StickyGridHeadersGridView.OnHeaderClickListener,
StickyGridHeadersGridView.OnItemClickListener,
StickyGridHeadersGridView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onHeaderClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, long l) {
        Log.i("asd","THE HEADER IS CLICKED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.i("asd","ITEM "+i+" IS CLICKED");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.i("asd","ITEM "+i+" IS LONG CLICKED");
        return true;
    }
```

**Custom Base Adapter**

```
public class MediaAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaitems;
ArrayList<GalleryItem> galleryItems;
LayoutInflater inflater;
HashMap<String,ImageView> imageHolder;

public MediaAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<GalleryItem> l) {
    mediaitems = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();
    galleryRef = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    mContext = c;
    galleryItems = l;
    imageHolder = new HashMap<String, ImageView>();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

public GalleryItem getSelectedGallery(String id){
        return ((Tidy)mContext.getApplicationContext()).startOrGetFileStore().getGalleryItem(id);
}

public int getCount() {
    return mediaitems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mediaitems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridView gv =(GridView)parent;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {// if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.media_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    imageManager.displayImage(holder.img);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCountForHeader(int i) {
    return galleryItems.get(i).getMediaLength();
}

@Override
public int getNumHeaders() {
    return galleryItems.size();
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(final int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder = new HeaderViewHolder();

    if(view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, viewGroup, false);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.settings = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.folder_settings);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (HeaderViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    GalleryItem galleryItem = galleryItems.get(pos);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(setIcon(galleryItem.getMode()));
    holder.title.setText(galleryItem.getTitle());
    Date da = galleryItem.record.getDate("FILE_DATE");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL-dd-yyyy");
    String mDate = dateFormat.format(da);
    holder.date.setText(mDate);
    holder.gallery = galleryItem.record;
    return view;
}

class HeaderViewHolder {
    DbxRecord gallery;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    TextView title;
    TextView date;
    ImageView icon;
    ImageView settings;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
}

}
```

**View XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/imagegrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the listener in the fragment/activity who hosts the StickyGrid

I made it to work like this:

```
@Override
public void onHeaderClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, long l) {
    view.findViewById(R.id.folder_settings).performClick();
}
```

For a header with just one clickable element it's ok. If the header has more than one element which can be clickable this solution won't work.

Comment: I appreciate the help Noya.  I still can't get it working with the above code. It is held in a fragment, so in the fragment class I am implementing `onHeaderClick` with the above code. When clicking anywhere in the header, it isn't even firing the `onHeaderClick` method.

Comment: In `onViewCreated()` in the fragment I am registering the GridView like so `final StickyGridHeadersGridView listview = (StickyGridHeadersGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagegrid);` then setting the adapter, then the `listview.setOnItemClick()` then `listview.setOnHeaderClickListener(this);` Is this right?

Comment: It seems to be right. The only thing i did differently was to use a ViewHolder (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) for the headerView too like the one I use for normal ListView items...

Comment: I checked the layout bounds on my device to see if the Headers were showing up and they are not drawing any bounds, paddings, or margins. Could this be part of the problem? Are they somehow not rendering correctly and thus not recognized in the view?

Comment: by the way, I implemented a `ViewHolder` in the `getHeaderView()` with no luck. Not sure what is going on...