# Why am I getting a NullPointerException using StickyGridHeaders library, while others are using the same library just fine?

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception, android-gridview

I am getting a `NullPointerException` in the [StickyGridHeaders library](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders), while others ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802098/using-stickygridheaders)) and ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634777/button-in-header-when-implementing-stickygridheaders-android)) seem to be using it without this exception.

I should probably also mention that I am adding the `.jar` file of the library in my project, because I use Eclipse (rather than Android Studio).

How can I solve this problem?

***Part of Logcat:***

```
...
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter.getHeaderView(StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter.java:93)
...
```

***SSCCE:***

***MainActivity.java:***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private StickyGridHeadersGridView mainGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainGridView = (StickyGridHeadersGridView) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_gridView);

        final String[] dataArray = {
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                "F",
                "G",
                "H",
                "I",
                "J",
        };

        StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter<String> stickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapter = 
                new StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), dataArray, R.layout.header,
                R.layout.item);
        mainGridView.setAdapter(stickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapter);

        mainGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Item labelled " + dataArray[position] + "clicked.");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml:***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView android:id="@+id/mainActivity_gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="#90000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***header.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff33b5e5" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***item.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

---

***Edit:***

```
06-24 08:42:22.415: W/dalvikvm(1495): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62ad288)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter.getHeaderView(StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter.java:93)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapterWrapper.getHeaderView(StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapterWrapper.java:57)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper.getView(StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper.java:172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView.onMeasure(StickyGridHeadersGridView.java:822)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-24 08:42:22.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1495):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 08:47:22.611: I/Process(1495): Sending signal. PID: 1495 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It looks like it's expecting IDs on the `TextView`s in your header and item layouts; specifically `@android:id/text1` for both, if the linked code is actually what you're running. The complete stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: For Mike comment clerfication visit this : https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Example/res/layout/item.xml and https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Example/res/layout/header.xml.

Comment: @MikeM. Posted complete stack trace in the question

Comment: Well, that's not very informative. Yeah, try adding the IDs on your `TextView`s.

Comment: @MikeM. Didn't help. =(

Comment: I just tested your posted code and the linked repo code, and that's the only thing that's wrong. If you're sure you added `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to both of the `TextView`s in your posted layouts, then try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: @MikeM. When you tested my code, was the error corrected by adding `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to the `TextView`s?

Comment: @MikeM. Were you using Eclipse or Android Studio? Did you use the .jar file of the library or did you include the project in Android Studio?

Comment: Neither. And I just copied the code directly into a project. I downloaded the zipped repo.

Comment: If you're still having problems, you may need to go a few more steps. Eclipse can be quite uncooperative, as I recall. Uninstall/reinstall your app, restart your IDE, reboot the device/emulator, clean/rebuild again, etc. If you've done all that and it still crashes, check to see if the stack trace has changed at all, even if just the line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made it work in Eclipse. Here is what I did:

1. Create a new project named `StickyGridHeaders` in Eclipse. Make it a
   library project and make a package
   `com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders` inside it. Do not create
   any Activity.
2. Create six classes in the package, and give them the same names as
   the names of classes [here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/tree/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders).
3. Open each of the classes [here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/tree/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders) and copy the code to the
   corresponding class in your Eclipse library project. Save them.
4. Now, in your actual SSCCE project, in `header.xml` and `item.xml`,
   in the `TextView` element, add `android:id="@android:id/item1"`
   attribute. Thanks to Mike M.'s comments for this step.
5. From your SSCCE project, remove the .jar file of the library you had
   previously included.
6. In your SSCCE project, add this project like you would
       add any other project from your workspace.

***Reason:***

In your stack trace, Line 93 of `StickyGridHeadersSimpleArrayAdapter` is mentioned but this line is blank in the Github version of class. Line 172 of `StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper` is mentioned in accorance with `getView()` method, but this line is in `getItemViewType()` method and does not call `getView()` either.

So I concluded that the `.jar` is of a previous version of the project..